# Своя криптовалюта и uid

Tags: bitcoin

Сейчас любой желающий может создать свою криптовалюту.
При создании своей криптовалюты её имя проверятся на уникальность?
Что если множество создаст множество токенов или криптовалют с одинаковыми именами?  Проясните пожалуйста, кто в теме.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В криптовалют нет никакого уникального имени. Есть порт, через который общаются ноды, и есть формат транзакций/блоков. Например, для биткоина используется порт 8333, для лайткоина 9333. Даже если создать 2 криптовалюты которые будут использовать один порт, транзакции/блоки будут невалидны, если они принадлежат другой крипте. Так что все будет работать.

Comment: BTC Bitcoin , LTC Litecoin - символьный код и уникальные имена . Или чего я не понимаю ?

Comment: Эти имена придуманы для бирж, ровно так же как американский доллар это USD а российский рубль это RUB. В архитектуре самой сети эти имена не фигурируют.